# How can one get a status badge for the latest Azure DevOps pipeline run irrespective of branch that triggered the pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Currently, there is no way to get a status badge for the latest pipeline run irrespective of the branch that triggered the pipeline. One either gets the latest pipeline run status for the default branch, or the specified branch. But if one were to use feature branches or versioned tags to run pipelines from, the only way to get the status is to manually update the status badge branch, which is not maintainable.

[This issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/status-badge-for-all-branches-latest-build/684754) seems to cover it, but there doesn’t seem to be a solution for the issue.

[Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Ability-to-get-status-badge-for-latest-p/10527472) is a link to the related issue I captured on Azure's dev community.

[Here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/13826) is a link to the GitHub issue I captured on Azure's repo.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no workaround to set a status badge to show the latest build status irrespective of the branches for the build.

It is recommended reporting a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

I noticed that you have reported the feature request on Developer Community. And I also have helped to vote up on your feature request.

---

Comment: @JPStrydom, Is there any update from you?